# Hosting a few shapefiles so multiple users could use and edit the same map

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, cloud-gis, qgis-cloud

Is there a way to synchronize a QGIS map with vector layers so that 3 or 4 users can use and edit the same file?   I have a plug-in that updates shapefiles on a layer and it would be great to synchronize this on a cloud service.   I have tried QGIS Cloud and it doesn't seem to work well with vector layers.

http://support.qgiscloud.com/kb/index.php

Comment: Given that shapefiles have three distinct data files and no built-in support for concurrency, this is an ambitious goal.

Comment: I loaded the files onto our network and got everything working with the Plug-in and a boat load of troubleshooting.  I also looked into Google Cloud Services and that worked well also.

Answer (score 2):

You can try cloud GIS by NextGIS (http://nextgis.com):

1. Get you free web GIS at http://nextgis.com.
2. Install [NextGIS Connect](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/nextgis_connect/) QGIS plugin. **Note**: Only QGIS 2.x now
3. Load you ESRI shapefiles into web GIS.
4. Create WFS service and add you vector layers in it.
5. Share the WFS link to our users.

See [documentation](http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngcom/source/toc.html).

**Disclosure**: I'm developer at NextGIS.

Comment: I am running a QGIS 3 Plug-in and was hoping to stick with that.    This looks great.

Comment: You can still stay on QGIS 3 but upload your shapefiles and create WFS service [using web interface](http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngcom/source/data_upload.html#vector-data)

Comment: This looks very promising,   Can several users work on the map and edit it at the same time?

Comment: @CaryHutchinson yes they can, but the WFS-T protocol has no conflict resolution: if two users edit the same feature the latest save will overwrite any previous edits. Is this usual case in your work?

Comment: @DmitryBaryshnikov - Your answer is very useful - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can serve WFS and WFS-T with QGIS Cloud. Please have a look at [How to make WFS and WFS-T with QGIS Cloud](http://support.qgiscloud.com/kb/faq.php?id=12)